# What does functional_qml_application_uses_QtWebKit mean?

Tags: application-development

In a review for my click package, I saw the following  message:

```
functional_qml_application_uses_QtWebKit
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the QtWebKit test is a warning, not an error. Application developers are free to use QtWebKit, however there are major caveats:

- qtwebkit *won't get security support* (not from Ubuntu/Canonical nor Upstream) and
- once Ubuntu moves to oxide, won't be getting as much testing and its utility will likely decrease (indeed, future Qt versions will drop it entirely). Then you will be able to 'import Oxide' if you should need more functionality than from UbuntuWebView.

UbuntuWebView will always work, get the testing and get the security updates since it will be using Oxide. [Oxide](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=196), once integrated with UbuntuWebview will also bring performance improvements and added functionality over QtWebKit. This should not block app approval, but may slow down the review process and it is highly recommended that app developers use UbuntuWebview whenever possible.

If you are currently suffering from shortcomings in UbuntuWebView, please file bugs on the webbrowser-app project in Launchpad.